# Как реализовать определение жестов только на ViewFlipper?

Tags: gestures, android, java

Реализовал небольшой контрол с использованием ViewFlipper'а реагирующий на жесты. Но только вот он реагирует на жесты везде, а мне нужно чтобы он их определял только на ViewFlipper.

Ниже мой код:

```
ViewFlipper flipper;

    Animation animFlipInForward;
    Animation animFlipOutForward;
    Animation animFlipInBackward;
    Animation animFlipOutBackward;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dost_yi);

        flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.rel1);

        animFlipInForward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
        animFlipOutForward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_out);
        animFlipInBackward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.slide_right_in);
        animFlipOutBackward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.slide_left_out);
    }

    private void SwipeLeft() {
        flipper.setInAnimation(animFlipInBackward);
        flipper.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutBackward);
        flipper.showPrevious();
    }

    private void SwipeRight() {
        flipper.setInAnimation(animFlipInForward);
        flipper.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutForward);
        flipper.showNext();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {

            float sensitvity = 50;
            if ((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity) {
                SwipeLeft();
            } else if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity) {
                SwipeRight();
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getBaseContext(),
            simpleOnGestureListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот [статейка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/118482/), когда-то по ней делал.